# Swift 5 - How to get AVPlayer duration

Tags: swift, avplayer, nan, ios13

I'm trying to get the duration of audio using AVPlayer [not AVAudioPlayer], but its always retrieving a NaN.

here's what I'm doing:

```
let urlString = dataModel.currentPodcast.url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let asset = AVAsset(url: URL.init(string: urlString!)!)
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}

self.epTotalTime.text = self.secondsToFormattedString(player.currentItem.asset.duration)
```

so I've tried to do this:

```
durationObserver = playerItem?.observe(\AVPlayerItem.status, changeHandler: { observedPlayerItem, change in
  if (observedPlayerItem.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay) {
    self.epTotalTime.text = self.secondsToFormattedString(totalSeconds: CMTimeGetSeconds(observedPlayerItem.asset.duration))
  }
})
```

and here totalSeconds is still a NaN:

```
private func secondsToFormattedString(totalSeconds: Float64) -> String {

  guard !(totalSeconds.isNaN || totalSeconds.isInfinite) else {
    return "--:--"
  }
    
  let hours:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 86400) / 3600)
  let minutes:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)
  let seconds:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))

  if hours > 0 {
    return String(format: "%i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
  } else {     
    return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the format of the item that's being played? Is it a format that promises a duration?  Some streaming formats have no durations (they may be live streams). You should check first `CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE(duration)`.

Comment: @RobNapier It's a mp3 file (podcasts). it was running for 2 weeks than stopped

Comment: If it worked and then stopped, I would look at the data coming from the server. Does it still provide a duration? Did the server change? And does `CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE(duration)` return true? (That would mean it's not reading a duration)

Comment: @RobNapier Server did not change and CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE(duration) returns true. If I save the file, this code works.